# PID-controller and Ziegler-Nichols Method: How to get oscillation period?

Tags: pid-controller

I'm a bit confused about how to measure the oscillation period of a quasi-stable system when using the Ziegler-Nichols method to get the correct PID configuration. The factor of the oscillation period is used in the rule for the I and D terms, but in what unit? seconds, milliseconds, minutes? Does it have something to do with the sampling time of my digital PID controller?

[image: Table of settings where Pcr is the "critical period"]

**Pcr** is used here for describing the critical period (at the critical gain **Kcr** setting)

Comment: It's in seconds. This article explains it all very well: http://www.mstarlabs.com/control/znrule.html

Comment: My PID controller also has a variable sample time and that sampling time is in milliseconds, and it's used to calculate the factor of Ti (Ki = Kp * (Tsample/Ti)) So I guessed I need to refactor the period time (which can be measured in seconds) to the sampling time I used. For example: if I used a sampling time of 20 ms, and the oscillation period is 1 second, Ti should be: 1 * 1000 [ms] / 20 [/20ms], right?

Comment: My experience is that you'll drive yourself BATS trying to control a system with any complexity using a variable sample time.  Do you really mean variable, or can you set it to be some constant in some range, but you can change that?

Comment: Yes, I mean the second part. so I can set the sample time to be 20 ms, or 1 second for example. After that it's fixed. But should there be a difference in the number I put in for Pcr in case of 20 ms sampling time, or, for example, 1 second sampling time. That's my main concern :)

Comment: I don't think sample time was considered when Z-N was developed (the original paper was published in 1942).

Answer (score 2):

The figure below shows the steps in order to find the \$K_{cr}\$(or \$K_u\$) and \$P_{cr}\$ (or \$P_u)\$, by changing the proportional gain only (with \$T_d=0\$ and \$T_i=\infty\$) - an example for temperature control:

[image: PID ZN]

The time unit to be used should be consistent with its response curve. The relationship with the **sample period** \$\Delta t\$ can be obtained, after the discretization of the PID controller. Using  the **standard form**, in contrast with other implementations (for example, when the derivative term is taken from output):

$$u(t)=K_pe(t)+\frac{K_p}{T_i}\int_0^t{e(\tau)d\tau+K_pT_d\frac{de(t)}{dt}}$$

Taking the derivative of \$u(t)\$:
$$u'(t)=K_pe'(t)+\frac{K_p}{T_i}e(t)+K_pT_de''(t)$$
A possible approach: To approximate the first and second derivatives using finite differences (eg backward), where \$k\$ is the sample id:
$$x'(t)\approx\frac{x_k-x_{k-1}}{\Delta t}$$
$$x''(t)\approx\frac{x_k-2x_{k-1}+x_{k-2}}{\Delta t^2}$$
So, the discrete PID controller takes the form (*velocity algorithm*):
$$u_k=u_{k-1}+K_p[(1+\frac{\Delta t}{T_i}+\frac{T_d}{\Delta t})e_k+(-1-\frac{2T_d}{\Delta t})e_{k-1}+\frac{T_d}{\Delta t}e_{k-2}]$$

Alternative definitions can include \$K_i=\frac{K_p}{T_i}\$ and \$K_d=K_pT_d\$. Also, the derivative term can be modified in order to reduce issues with high frequency noise - eg a low pass filter. Other discretization methods exist as well, such as Tustin, ZOH.

FURTHER EXPLANATION:

1. Choose a sample time \$\Delta t\$ consistent with your process. There is extensive literature on the subject. For example, to avoid aliasing \$F_S > 2F_{BW}\$. In practice:  Sampling frequency should be 10 to 30 times the bandwidth freq.
2. Set \$K_p\$ to some low value (with \$T_i=\infty\$ and \$T_d=0\$ at this stage).  So, the above equation is simplified to:
   $$u_k=u_{k-1}+K_p(e_k-e_{k-1})$$
3. Implement the previous equation (a P controller) in your digital system along with that suitable \$\Delta t\$, testing \$K_p\$ to see if it causes continuum oscillation (marginally stable).  If the oscillations decay, keep increasing \$K_p\$.  If the oscillations increase in amplitude (unstable system), reduce \$K_p\$.  Do this until the system is marginally stable.  When you arrive at this point, you have found \$K_{cr}=K_p\$ and \$P_{cr}=\$oscillation period (see the figure above).
4. Using the table you have provided (also above), determine the \$K_p\$, \$T_i\$ and \$T_d\$ values from the \$K_{cr}\$ and \$P_{cr}\$ ones.
5. Implement the complete PID controller:
   $$u_k=u_{k-1}+K_p[(1+\frac{\Delta t}{T_i}+\frac{T_d}{\Delta t})e_k+(-1-\frac{2T_d}{\Delta t})e_{k-1}+\frac{T_d}{\Delta t}e_{k-2}]$$

Comment: I understand how the implementation of an PID controller works but for the Ziegler-Nichols method I need the oscillation period. So let's say my the oscillation period is 1 second and my sampling time is 1 sample/20ms, which value do I need to enter for Pcr? is that 1 or (1second/20ms) 50?

Comment: OK, then you know the step 5 described above. But please, pay attention to the step 3. In this case, considering that you applied that procedure and measured an oscillation period of 1 second, then Pcr = 1 second. The sample time appears explicitly on the complete equation for PID (not on P controller used for the ZN method - step 2). Of course, it assumes that you have chosen a suitable sample time value, for example << Pcr.

Comment: Should this always work? I've run into some applications where setting incrementing Kp never produces a stable oscillation that leads to meaningful Ku/Tu parameters. Decrementing Kp gets a stable oscillation, but the ZN calculated PID params are nonsensical.